# response.redirect takes too much time to load a page

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

I am using a repeater control in my page and bound records from stored procedure. It has about a thousand records. I have used the pagination as well. I have a column for link button to navigate into a another page like below.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Link1" CommandName="link"
 CommandArgument="222">
```

In code behind

```
 Protected Sub repeater1_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
       Select Case e.CommandName
            Case "link"         
                  Response.Redirect("/page2.aspx?" & e.CommandArgument, False)    
       End Select
 End Sub
```

When clicking on the "Link" button it opens the page2 and takes about 25 seconds. There is only code in page2 load event to show the command argument in a textbox. So Why it is taking much time to load the page ? If there are only few records, its working fine. Here I am using a parent and a child repeater to bind the records in order to show the record grouping.
   I tried to trace the child page (page2.aspx) load event as well the master page (overall master page) load event. All seems taking less time.

Comment: Your postback is taking a long time. Probably also your viewstate.

Why not render actual links?

Comment: Have you used Fiddler to see the times? A `Response.Redirect` is a client-side redirect, so it actually requires more trips to the client/server. Have you tried a `Server.Transfer` instead?

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin. I have set the viewstate property as false. But it is not go and call the repeater's Itemcommand event when click on link button.

Comment: Thanks Dominic. I didn't use fiddler. I have passed some values through response.redirect as querystring.